# Do "yellow"-light bulbs attract fewer bugs than standard bulbs?

Tags: entomology

I read a article on [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_2060109_repel-mosquitoes.html) which claims that that yellow light-bulbs attract fewer bugs.

> Replace outdoor lights with "yellow" bulbs which attract fewer bugs than standard outdoor bulbs.

Is it true?

Comment: [Article](http://blog.1000bulbs.com/do-yellow-bug-light-bulbs-work/) on whether bug lights actually work, how they work, and why they attract fewer bugs.